# How to configure Facebook login via firebase/ionic

Tags: facebook, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase

Hello I don't get any further with the Facebook authentication in Firebase.

Under Authorized Domains for OAuth Redirects in Firebase I've set this 3 domains

1. localhost
2. 127.0.0.1
3. <-my Firebase url->

And under the Facebook App settings in site-url I have set my firebase url. Also I tried with the method to configure the hosts file with a local domain.

But always if I want to login to Facebook with my webapp I get this message: The app's settings do not allow the specified URL: One or more URLS are not allowed in the settings.

Does anybody here can tell me how I can fix this? I've already tried all day.

Answer (score 2):

In Facebook app settings go to the **Advanced** tab and under **Client OAuth Settings** enter the URL that is something like `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/yourFirebaseAppName/auth/facebook/callback`.

Please note the **Advanced** tab, not the main **Basic** tab.

Along with the settings that you have to do in your Firebase account (and they are straight forward if you've followed the [official tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html)) you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: I've tried all possible configurations like the advanced settings I typed my callback url from firebase there. But nothing helps. I don't know where the problem is. 
My settings so far:

Facebook basic settings: site-url -> http://localhost:8080/
Facebook advanced settings: localhost:8080 and my callback url from Firebase

Comment: most probably, as I suspect, that you've mixed them. The only one which should really be there is the one I answered. Of course, plus the settings on the Firebase side.

Comment: Please have a look at my settings again:
 Facebook basic settings: site-url -> localhost:8080 
Facebook advanced settings: localhost:8080 and my callback url from Firebase and I don't know really why it's not working.

Comment: Because, as I said, you should **not** have anything in the basic settings. And, your advanced settings are just wrong. You should put the firebase link there only, without the localhost.

Comment: Again I have got the same message from Facebook. My basic settings are empty and advanced settings is only the callback url from firebase. To be sure here are 2 screens. 
http://oi61.tinypic.com/de2qyq.jpg and http://oi58.tinypic.com/2d7ai6f.jpg

Comment: Did you do this "Facebook requires that you have a valid contact email specified in order to make your app available to all users. You can specify this email address from the same Basic tab within the Settings section. After you have provided your email, click on Save Changes. The last thing you need to do to approve your app is click on the Status & Review tab on the left-hand navigation menu and move the slider at the top of that page to the Yes position. When prompted with a popup, click Confirm. Your app will now be live and can be used with Firebase Authentication."?

Comment: All the settings were set before already. But maybe I have to go for another approach.

Comment: had a misspelling at the url and it works now but after the redirect the authData is null.

Comment: Most likely you've missed something else then too. Because, I was just following the official tutorial: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html and everything turned out as expected.